# Extending SonataMedia

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, sonata-admin

I'm using Symfony 2.3 and I have installed SonataMediaBundle. Upload works fine. I also install ckeditor ("egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "2.*",). CK editor works fine.

Then I install "tilleuls/ckeditor-sonata-media-bundle": "dev-master", because I want to upload file via ckeditor - [link](https://github.com/coopTilleuls/CoopTilleulsCKEditorSonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/install.md).

Installation manual says that I have to extend sonataMedia with command:

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate CoopTilleulsCKEditorSonataMediaBundle
```

This command gives me an error:

```
[LogicException]                                                                                                                            
      Bundle "SonataMediaBundle" is directly extended by two bundles "CoopTilleulsCKEditorSonataMediaBundle" and "ApplicationSonataMediaBundle".
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update ApplicationSonataMediaBundle bundle file to specify CoopTilleulsCKEditorSonataMediaBundle as parent:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return 'CoopTilleulsCKEditorSonataMediaBundle';
}
```

see [install](https://github.com/coopTilleuls/CoopTilleulsCKEditorSonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/install.md#directly)